# Extracting max value of each row in a matrix and output their column names

Tags: r, loops, matrix, max

I am experimenting with `SVM` function on `iris` data. The objective is to extract the "class" of highest predicted probability for (1) each row (2) from the output matrix `attr(pred_prob, "probabilities")`.

```js
data(iris)
attach(iris)
x <- subset(iris, select = -Species) 
y <- Species
model <- svm(x, y, probability = TRUE)
pred_prob <- predict(model, x, decision.values = TRUE, probability = TRUE)
attr(pred_prob, "probabilities")
```

(The original code came from this previous [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34328105/how-to-build-multiclass-svm-in-r).)
The last line of code will give us an output of the following format:

```js
       setosa  versicolor   virginica
1 0.979989881 0.011347796 0.008662323
2 0.972567961 0.018145783 0.009286256
3 0.978668604 0.011973933 0.009357463
```

For ease of comparing these predicted probabilities with their real class "labels" (i.e., setosa, versicolor, virginica), I plan to extract the class of highest predicted probability for each row from the above output matrix. For example, the class of highest probability for the first observation is `setosa` with predicted probability of 0.9799, which is returned from

```
which(attr(pred_prob, "probabilities")[1,] == max(attr(pred_prob, "probabilities")[1,]), arr.ind = TRUE)
```

I am now working on extending the above code into a loop in order to output a data column containing predicted class label for each observation in the data. Below is what I have so far, but I am having a hard time

```js
predicted_class <- attr(pred_prob, "probabilities")
for(row in 1:nrow(predicted_class)) {
output <- print(which(predicted_class[row,] == max(predicted_class[row,]), arr.ind = TRUE))
output
}
```

But this does not give me what I intended it to be, it seems only to return the predicted class from a random row (while I want to a column of predicted classes for all observations).
Could anyone enlighten me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `max.col`

```
colnames(pred_prob)[max.col(pred_prob)]
#[1] "setosa" "setosa" "setosa"
```

---

Or using a loop

```
output <- vector("double", nrow(pred_prob))

for(row in 1:nrow(pred_prob)) {
  output[row] <- which.max(pred_prob[row,])
}

output
#[1] 1 1 1
```

---

Or `apply`

```
apply(pred_prob, MARGIN = 1, FUN = which.max)
#1 2 3 
#1 1 1
```

**data**

```
pred_prob <- structure(c(0.979989881, 0.972567961, 0.978668604, 0.011347796, 
0.018145783, 0.011973933, 0.008662323, 0.009286256, 0.009357463
), .Dim = c(3L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3"), c("setosa", 
"versicolor", "virginica")))
```